# How to bind key on midi keyboard to send enter input?

Tags: keyboard, key-binding, midi

I have a midi keyboard connected to my `Windows 8.1 x64` PC and I want to setup one of it's key to send enter input, I want one of it's keys to behave like enter. Is it possible to do and if so - how?

Comment: Yes, but what software to use depends on the OS.

Comment: @CL, I've added the update. I have Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS has no built-in mechanism for this; you need to install some separate MIDI-to-keyboard software (e.g., [Bome MIDI Translator](http://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator/overview/classic)).